# OrderList component works until submit the page

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a page with an orderList component that is working partially.

This is the orderList

[image]

It has a list of names and also hold the ID for each system.

```
<p:orderList id="orderListAppList" value="#{manageApplications.listOfApplicationsAndIds}" var="app" controlsLocation="none" itemLabel="#{app.applicationName}" itemValue="#{app.applicationId}" >
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{manageApplications.onSelect}"/>
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{manageApplications.onUnselect}"/>
</p:orderList>
```

This is working as expected until I have added a button on the page that execute with ajax=false

When I click on this new button the error below is being thrown

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'applicationId' not found on type java.lang.String

This is the code that load the ArrayList used in the orderList component

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManageApplications implements Serializable {

    private List<ApplicationNameAndId> listOfApplicationsAndIds = new ArrayList<ApplicationNameAndId>();


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        populateApplications();
    }

    private void populateApplications() {

        // HERE I LOAD THE APPLICATION'S LIST FROM THE DATABASE
        listOfApplicationsAndIds = manageDbApplications.getApplicationsListFromDatabase();

    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public List<ApplicationNameAndId> getListOfApplicationsAndIds() {
        return listOfApplicationsAndIds;
    }

    public void setListOfApplicationsAndIds(List<ApplicationNameAndId> listOfApplicationsAndIds) {
        this.listOfApplicationsAndIds = listOfApplicationsAndIds;
    }
}
```

This is the type *ApplicationNameAndId*

public class ApplicationNameAndId implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2031225157408650765L;

    String applicationId;
    String applicationName;

    public ApplicationNameAndId() {
    }

    public ApplicationNameAndId(String appName, String appId) {
        this.applicationId = appId;
        this.applicationName = appName;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS 
    public String getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public String getApplicationName() {
        return applicationName;
    }

    public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }
}
```

My point is.

The component is working normally until I use some button with **ajax=false**.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{manageApplications.selectQueuesToAddToAnExistingApplication(qmgr.queueManagerNameId)}" 
oncomplete="PF('dlgAddQueuesToApplication').show();" 
update=":j_idt3:addQueuesToApplicationPanel" 
value="ADD QUEUE" ajax=false icon="fa fa-plus">
</p:commandButton>
```

Note that the "button" that I am talking about has nothing do to with the oederList component. Just adding a button that execute a listener (or something) with ajax=fase generate this error.

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, please create a [mcve]. Otherwise it is next to impossible to check what is really wrong

Comment: Hi Kukeltje. O have added the code for the same. Not something important. This work as expected until I use a button with ajax=false.

I don't get why this is happening. May be an issue reloading the content? Did I break some rule perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the object that I was using.

The Application on my application's list is a Class that can be represented this way:

```
public class ApplicationNameAndId {
    String applicationId;
    String applicationName;

// CONSTRUCTOR
// GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE
}
```

The orderList component does not deal with your own object type, this expect to receive a List of Strings instead.

```
List<String> ListOfStringToBeUsed
```

For now I have adapted my code to return the list of Strings as expected.

When having more time I will create a custom converter class (to use my own object type) than post the how to here.

I hope this helps someone else,
Neliosam